# How to limit the display of a layer in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a plot with two layers, a geom_point and a stat_smooth, how can I limit the stat_smooth layer to only display for a particular span of the x-axis?

Here's a simple working example:
http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=qfnAsk3H&version=4

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))    
p + stat_smooth(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))
```

Say I only want stat_smooth to show from x=3 to the end of the graph.

Can this be done?

If I create a copy of mtcars limited to x>=3 and use that as the data for stat_smooth, it will change the trendline (it gets fat at the end) which I can't have.  I just want to mask it, or only display the portion x>=3.

Comment: Your example is different here and on r-fiddle.

Comment: The general recommendation is that once you move much beyond the capabilities of the "built-in" smoothing in ggplot the best option is to fit the model outside of ggplot and draw the curve yourself with a data frame of predicted values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the data from the original plot using `ggplot_build`. This will provide you with the datapoints that can be used to rebuild the `stat_smooth` on the interval you want. I have use `geom_line` an `geom_ribbon` here, perhaps there are other ways to do it too.

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars_plus_three <- mtcars[mtcars$wt > 3, ]
p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))
p_full <- p + stat_smooth(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) 

data_full_range <- ggplot_build(p_full)$data[[2]]
data_full_range <- data_full_range[data_full_range$x > 3, ]
p + geom_line(data = data_full_range, aes(x = x, y = y), col = 'blue') +
geom_ribbon(data = data_full_range, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .5)
```

Comment: I can't make the leap form your snippet to working code.  Do you think you could make this runnable and then I should be able to apply it to my own work?  I'm an R and ggplot noob =)

e.g.: `Error : object 'p_full' not found`

http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=fWXyO3fI&version=1

Comment: My bad, very sorry. Forgot to copy paste a line ;)