# Recreate a ggplot layer from ggplot_build data where color = some_discrete_value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot where the trendline has been "masked" to a specific domain, in this example x<1.5, by creating the stat_smooth layer, converting it to data, and cutting the data off at x<1.5 (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239797/how-to-limit-the-display-of-a-layer-in-ggplot2/32242123#32242123))

```
library(ggplot2)
mysample <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), 500,   replace=FALSE),] 

p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=mysample, aes(x=carat, y=price))
p_full <- p + stat_smooth(data=mysample, aes(x=carat, y=price)) 

data_full_range <- ggplot_build(p_full)$data[[2]]
data_full_range <- data_full_range[data_full_range$x < 1.5, ]
p + geom_line(data = data_full_range, aes(x = x, y = y), col = 'blue') +
geom_ribbon(data = data_full_range, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .5)
```

I need to do the same thing, but have the trends separated by some parameter.  For example, by clarity:

```
library(ggplot2)
#just to limit data making it easier to see what's going on
mysample <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), 1000,   replace=FALSE),] 

p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=mysample, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=clarity))
p + stat_smooth(data=mysample, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=clarity))
```

How can I do the equivalent to the first script; mask the trends at x<1.5, but with the data separated like in the second script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add clarity as a grouping variable then use group=group when recreating the figure.

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=mysample, aes(x=carat, y=price))
p_full <- p + stat_smooth(data=mysample, aes(x=carat, y=price,group=clarity)) 

data_full_range <- ggplot_build(p_full)$data[[2]]
data_full_range <- data_full_range[data_full_range$x < 1.5, ]
p + geom_line(data = data_full_range, aes(x = x, y = y, group=group), col = 'blue') +
    geom_ribbon(data = data_full_range, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, 
    ymax = ymax, group = group), alpha = .5)
```

Can use p_full as a test of whether the trends are keeping to the original pattern(s).

```
p_full + geom_line(data = data_full_range, aes(x = x, y = y, group=group), col = 'blue') +
geom_ribbon(data = data_full_range, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax,
            group = group), alpha = .5)
```

Comment: I need to do that same thing as in the first example.  I can't just stat_smooth on a subset because it changes the trend at the endpoint.

Comment: I updated the code to complete the task you requested. It isn't clear to me why you would want to include data for the trend lines yet not show the full trends, but many things are unclear to me.

Comment: I'm trying to fake a break in the x-axis (similar to MatLab's BreakXAxis)

Comment: example in case you're curious =) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_in_the_Canadian_federal_election,_2015